# What does an empty regular expression mean in POSIX BRE/ERE?

Tags: regex, posix, glibc, posix-ere

Take following API regex_match as example, if I invoke it with regex_match(any_string_here,""), you can see I passed an empty regular expression here, then it always return 0, which means match successfully. So, what does an empty regular expression mean in POSIX BRE/ERE?

empty regular expression means I pass "" to the glibc regcomp function. See following example.

```
int regex_match( const char* haystack, const char* needle )
{
        regex_t needle_pattern;
        int regex_flag = REG_NOSUB | REG_EXTENDED;
        int rc = regcomp(&needle_pattern,needle, regex_flag);
        if (rc != 0){
                char error_msg[256];
                size_t error_len = 0;
                error_len = regerror(rc,&needle_pattern,error_msg,sizeof(error_msg));
                error_len = error_len < sizeof(error_msg) ? error_len : sizeof(error_msg) - 1;
                error_msg[error_len] = '\0';
                cout<<"compile error: "<<error_msg<<endl;
                regfree(&needle_pattern);
                return regcomp_error_base + rc;
        }
        rc = regexec(&needle_pattern, haystack, 0, NULL, 0);
        if ( (rc != 0) && (rc != REG_NOMATCH)){
                char error_msg[256];
                size_t error_len = 0;
                error_len = regerror(rc,&needle_pattern,error_msg,sizeof(error_msg));
                error_len = error_len < sizeof(error_msg) ? error_len : sizeof(error_msg) - 1;
                error_msg[error_len] = '\0';
                cout<<"exec error: "<<error_msg<<endl;
        }
        regfree(&needle_pattern);
        //regexec returns 0 if the regular expression matches
        return rc;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what an `empty` expression means. I mean, is it this `//` or this `/^$/` or `/.*?/`. I guess if it matches nothing, it can't be assumed as an empty expression, and probably doesn't say anything about the subject string either. The best bet is to test the subject and regex strings for length before using them.

Comment: POSIX regex grammar does not allow empty pattern. The behavior is undefined. You may end up with an infinite loop (which is the case with MacOS C++).

Comment: I guess they keyword is that it _matched_ something, although it matched nothing literally.

Comment: @sln empty regular expression means I pass "" to the glibc regcomp function. e.g. regcomp(&needle_pattern,"", regex_flag);

Comment: @stribizhev glibc function regcomp allow empty regular expression, please see my example.

Comment: @gemfield - That's the point, unless specified, engines take _empty_ expressions as well as expressions that mean nothing that aren't empty. All these give the same result - _a match_. It means nothing that you have passed an empty string as a regular expression.

Comment: @sln - "All these give the same result - a match", is this defined by a standard? Or it is just common sense? If former, then can you point out the section of that standard documentation?

Answer (score 1):

This is the only reference I could find ([source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libcpp/libcpp-31/src/regex.cpp)):

```
case regex_constants::__re_err_empty:
    return "An empty regex is not allowed in the POSIX grammar.";
```

This means that it is up to the language regex implementation to define what the behavior is, POSIX has little to do with it.

**NOTE** that this error is missing in [regex.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lsof/lsof-49/lsof/regex.h)! In your case, you have an empty/null string match since you pass the empty string as the pattern. Here is what I found inside the [*regex.c* source code](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/mail/mutt/regex.c):

> For some patterns, e.g., **`(a?)?`, `p+j`** here points to the
>    end of the pattern.  We don't want to push such a point,
>    since when we restore it above, entering the switch will
>    increment `p` past the end of the pattern.  We don't need
>    to push such a point since we obviously won't find any more
>    fastmap entries beyond `pend`.  **Such a pattern can match
>
>    the null string, though.**

**So, an empty pattern matches empty string before the first symbol in the input string if a single search is performed and all empty strings before all symbols if a global search is performed**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess "" will occupy 1 byte in memory which is "\0", and "any_string_here" looks like "any_string_here\0" in memory, so "\0" always match "any_string_here\0".

Answer (score 0):

> POSIX has little to do with it.

Well, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) defines grammars for BRE/ERE. For example:

```
/* --------------------------------------------
   Extended Regular Expression
   --------------------------------------------
*/
extended_reg_exp   :                      ERE_branch
                   | extended_reg_exp '|' ERE_branch
                   ;
ERE_branch         :            ERE_expression
                   | ERE_branch ERE_expression
                   ;
ERE_expression     : one_char_or_coll_elem_ERE
                   | '^'
                   | '$'
                   | '(' extended_reg_exp ')'
                   | ERE_expression ERE_dupl_symbol
                   ;
one_char_or_coll_elem_ERE  : ORD_CHAR
                   | QUOTED_CHAR
                   | '.'
                   | bracket_expression
                   ;
ERE_dupl_symbol    : '*'
                   | '+'
                   | '?'
                   | '{' DUP_COUNT               '}'
                   | '{' DUP_COUNT ','           '}'
                   | '{' DUP_COUNT ',' DUP_COUNT '}'
                   ;
```

This grammar has no production for an empty regular expression, i. e. it is not permitted.

Answer (score -1):

An empty regular expression matches an empty string. If the search string is an empty string, it matches the whole thing. And if the search string is not empty, it matches the empty strings between each character of the search string.